# Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies to CRUD

Tags: python, sql, orm, flask, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to model an entity that can sometimes be a person or a company. There are serval ways to design it. I've decided on inheritance

```
class Investor(db.Model, ModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = "investors"
  building_type = db.Column(db.String(32))
  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "investors",
    'polymorphic_on': building_type
  }
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  first_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(32))
  last_name = db.Column(db.Unicode(32))

class IndividualInvestor(Investor, ModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = "individual_investors"
  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "individual_investors",
  }
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('investors.id'), primary_key=True)

class CompanyInvestor(Investor, ModelMixin):
  __tablename__ = "company_investors"
  __mapper_args__ = {
    "polymorphic_identity": "company_investors",
  }
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('investors.id'), primary_key=True)
```

so far so good, but there are a few problems how to do CRUD operation with ORM.

Users marks entry as company and server gets

```
if "company" == request.args.get("type"):
  investor = IndividualInvestor()
else:
  investor = CompanyInvestor()
update_model(investor, request.json)
```

Simplified model update

```
def update_model(model, json):
  for key, value in json.items():
    new_value = value
    current_type = str(model.__table__.c[key].type)  # only current properties 
    if current_type in CONVERT_FROM:
        new_value = CONVERT_FROM[current_type](value)
    setattr(model, key, new_value)
```

Is this right approach? How to update the model? `model.__table__` only current model columns (no base columns)

Comment: What is the code for ModelMixin class?

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi   `def __repr__(self): return unicode(self.__dict__)` etc